# Smooth Scrolling from other site

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, smoothing

at the moment I am using the following Script for a smooth scrolling effect:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

//smoothscroll
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(document).off("scroll");

    $('a').each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    $(this).addClass('active');

    var target = this.hash,
        menu = target;
    $target = $(target);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
    }, 500, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
        $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });
});
});

function onScroll(event){
var scrollPos = $(document).scrollTop();
$('#menu-center a').each(function () {
    var currLink = $(this);
    var refElement = $(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        $('#menu-center ul li a').removeClass("active");
        currLink.addClass("active");
    }
    else{
        currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
});
}`
```

It all works fine for the OnePager. But if I am on en "external site" for example the privacy policy and click on a menu point nothing happens. This might be because in the scripted I deactivated the links and replaced it with scrolling. I am not that good in jQuery, can you help me so that it also works form "external" sites? What do I have to add to the code?

Greetings

Comment: `But if I am on en "external site" for example the privacy policy` - How your website's Privacy page is "External"? Are you talking about redirecting from another page with Url + #id? Like you do in Wikipedia?

Comment: Hello, almost everything is on the index.html beside privacy and terms, they got their one file. For this pages I would like the menu to redirect to the menu point clicked, just as you said, Url+#id for example http://home.page#contact